# How to calculate distance between points on a line in arcgis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, distance

I created a series of points along a line (as a single feature point), in ArcGIS 10.1. I want to know the distance from one point to the next point along a line.  I would also like to know the simple near distance.

Does someone know how can I do this? The Near or Point Distance tools do not measure distance along a route, only Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 2):

If the line you are talking about is indeed a route, then you can use the tool "Locate features along route" - This will give you the measures of the points. The next step I would export the table to excel and then you can use a formula to calculate the distance between each point.

For example =B2-B1, then drag to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

1. Use the [Split Line at Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003w000000) tool

> Splits line features based on intersection or proximity to point
>   features.

2. Open up the attribute table of the output layer of split line and create a new numeric field called "length"
3. Right click on "length" field and and select Calculate Geometry, feature length